SwiftUI View with optional generic parameters with multiple clauses
From all I have read this may be impossible given that nil is untyped. But essentially I am trying to create my own Searchbar view that mimics as much of the interface of .searchable and .searchSuggestions as is reasonable.
The goal is that I can have a single declaration for this view. If the user wants to specify tokens or searchSuggestions they can. The struct will be prepared to handle the same breadth of possible types as there are in the searchable declaration (where C : RandomAccessCollection, C : RangeReplaceableCollection, T : View, C.Element : Identifiable) BUT the kicker is I also want them to be able to not specify tokens or searchSuggestions without having to even think about the fact that generics are involved.
So I created my view declaration like this:
struct Searchbar<C, T>: View where C : RandomAccessCollection, C : RangeReplaceableCollection, T : View, C.Element : Identifiable  {

    @State var tokens: C? = nil
    @State var searchSuggestions: C? = nil

And I would hopefully be able to use it like this:
Searchbar(searchText: $searchText)

or
Searchbar(tokens: ["Apple", "Banana", "Carrot"], token: { token in
   Text(token)
}, searchText: $searchText)

This has a clear problem. In the effort to allow the user to not need to specify tokens or suggestions if I want to I end up implicitly creating the need for a typed nil. Which I believe does not exist. So if you do the default Searchbar(searchText: $searchText) constructor you get a Generic Parameter C could not be inferred.
But the thing is I don't care about what C is and the body of Searchable will never use the values of any variable involving C or T because they are nil.
I suppose I was imagining I might be able to set up the struct in such a way that if the user did not want to specify tokens or suggestions the struct would just put some dummy generic type as the C and T argument and move on. Because the values would be nil it would never become an issue.
Perhaps the compiler isn't able to reason that I won't be using anything of C or T type in the case that the values are nil?
I am not guessing this is possible. Any ideas?

Binding comes from a parent it doesn’t have its own initial value. Initializing a binding with any value that isn’t coming from a parent is invalid

It's not clear what you are trying to do here. Can you show how you want to implement Searchbar.body and how Searchbar is designed to be used?

Ah thank you. The binding bit was my first error. I now have the error I expected to get about Generic parameter could not be inferred.

Added two ways I want to use the class.

I think making tokens and searchSuggestions generic types is a mistake.  They should be a protocol (that potentially wraps a generic) then the types don't need to be inferred

OK this sounds reasonable. I just do want to confirm that I would then also have to have a concrete implementation of that type for every different C and T type pair I wanted to pass in? Or is there a way for the compiler to jump from my literal to recognizing that it conforms to the protocol?
